# json_extract_path_text cast to int error

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to extract an integer from a JSON blob stored in a text field in amazon redshift. My query looks (roughly) like:

```
select json_extract_path_text(json_column, 'integer_field')::int from data;
```

However, I'm getting a strange error:

```
ERROR: Invalid digit, Value '1', Pos 0, Type: Integer
```

Why is '1' an invalid digit type? What is happening here?

Comment: Note that I'm casting this to int because `json_extract_path_text` returns a string.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out (thanks to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692833/regexp-substr-converted-output-is-not-casting-as-integer)) that when there is no `'integer_field'` in the JSON blob, the value returned is the empty string ''. For some reason, that is not supported by the cast to integer function. Weirdly enough, a non-empty string ' ' is just fine as input, so the following workaround solved the problem:

```
nullif(json_extract_path_text(json_column, 'integer_field'), ' ')::int
```

And now we know.